# Should ViewModel expose things like BitmapImage or ImageSource or an Audio File Buffer?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

Should the View Model expose the loaded bitmap image (BitmapImage class) or only should provide filenames and let the WPF controls load the image or load an audio file for instance.

What is correct from the View Model's role in the MVVM design pattern.

The reason I am asking this is that if WPF controls are allowed to load images from local storage, it will be difficult for the application to monitor which files are in use.

Edit: 
The problem arises when the application manages it's file resources(WinRT or WindowsPhone apps). The application cannot manage the file resources when WPF controls load the files and application will become indirectly dependent on the life cycle of WPF controls since the files cannot be deleted or modified till the WPF control releases it.

Also frameworks like caliburn Micro do not have the concept of code behind. So how should these cases be dealt with?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Personally I like to just expose the URI to the image (or resource) from the viewmodel.

This helps avoid bad habits - when you have a team under tight time constraints, it's easy to start letting bad code (such as UI references) slip into places where they shouldn't be.

So, treat the image or audio file as a *resource* and provide a URI to it - the view can then bind to this and expose it in whatever way it deems appropriate.

There is also no reason why code behind in the view cannot access the exposed URI via the `DataContext` of the view. I always have my viewmodels implement an interface specific to them (i.e. ViewModelA will implement IViewModelA), then any time some code from the view needs to access the viewmodel it does it via the interface, e.g.:

```
var myAudioUri = ((IViewModelA) DataContext).ThatAudioUri;
```

Answer (score 1):

In my project we have properties of BitmapImage type in our ViewModels. It gives us full control on how an when images are loaded, and also it allows us to unit test this properties.

Comment: How do you change the image source from view model?? I tried public ImageSource ImageName{set; get;} but it doesn't seem to work. It binds, but it is not accepting or something